# Transform an image to "vector path"

Tags: html, css

Im trying to convert an image to whatever is this "M2 0a2 2 0 0 0 -2 2v12a2 2 0 0 0 2 2h12a2 2 0 0 0 2 -2V2a2 2 0 0 0 -2 -2H2zm7.5 11h-4a0.5 0.5 0 0 1 -0.5 -0.5v-4a0.5 0.5 0 0 1 1 0v2.793l4.146 -4.147a0.5 0.5 0 0 1 0.708 0.708L6.707 10H9.5a0.5 0.5 0 0 1 0 1z"
I dont know the name sorry but if you can help me i would be veary pleased

Comment: That looks like a path within an svg. Could you describe more what you mean by 'converting an image to...' What image? Some simple ones (like this, which is an arrow) may be convertible to a vector form, many won't be.

Comment: i want to use an image that i have on my computer and turn it something like that "vector" that i posted in the exemple

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is an sag path attribute. You can view the corresponding svg path below.

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 30 30">
  <path d="M2 0a2 2 0 0 0 -2 2v12a2 2 0 0 0 2 2h12a2 2 0 0 0 2 -2V2a2 2 0 0 0 -2 -2H2zm7.5 11h-4a0.5 0.5 0 0 1 -0.5 -0.5v-4a0.5 0.5 0 0 1 1 0v2.793l4.146 -4.147a0.5 0.5 0 0 1 0.708 0.708L6.707 10H9.5a0.5 0.5 0 0 1 0 1z"/>
</svg>
```